# The topology of the Deck group of a covering map

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

I have never been interested in this before, and I have become interested in to find some answers and my teaching on the fundamental group has led me in this direction. Neither, I don't know if it suits for MO. So, please down-vote or vote-to-close after you provided some references.

I think if $X$ is semi-locally simply connected, path connnected, and locally path connected then for the universal cover $p:\widetilde{X}\to X$, its group of Deck transformations, say $\mathrm{Deck}(p)$ acts properly discontinuously on $X$, hence it is equipped with the discrete topology. This then would imply that any covering over $X$ must have discrete group of Deck transformations. Indeed, this does not imply that it is finite, infinite or even countable. So, it could be $\mathbb{R}^\delta$ that is $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the discrete topology. Is this conclusion correct?

So, if I wish to find a covering whose group of Deck transformations has a non-discrete topology then either $X$, the base space of my covering map, should not be semi-locally simply connected ( like the infinite earring) or $X$ should not be either path connected nor locally path connected. I wonder if there is a place that I can look for examples of such coverings where the topology of the Deck group is determined. I know that in Munkres's book there are some statements/exercises about this. But, anything more recent or some survey articles on this?

Comment: Isn't the group of deck transformations of the universal cover of $X$ identified with the fundamental group of $X$? There's quite a substantial literature on topologizing the fundamental group and related objects, which would seem to be relevant here. Some of the protagonists (e.g. Jeremy Brazas) are active on MO.

Comment: The first interesting case would have to be the Hawaiian earrings.  Have you looked at the literature? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring

Comment: I cannot tell what is "the" topology on the deck transformation group you are referring to. The subspace topology of the compact-open topology or something different? Or are you looking for choices? Also, what definition of "properly discontinuous" action are you using? It sounds like you're using a definition that involves the topology of the group.

Comment: In the end, covering maps are still locally trivial by definition even when the base space is the Hawaiian earring or something more complicated. This means that most of the usual suspect topologies on $Deck(p)$ will still be discrete when the covering space $\widetilde{X}$ is connected. There is, however, a large literature on generalized covering maps where the deck transformation group of the generalized covering maps are naturally non-discrete.

Comment: @ Jeremy Brazas Thanks for your comments. For a covering map $p:E\to X$ the group $\mathrm{Deck}(p)$ the topology I am interested in is the topology as a subspace $\mathrm{Homeo}(E)$, the group of homeomorphisms $E\to E$, where the latter is equipped with the compact-open topology.

Comment: @JeremyBrazas For a continuous action of a topological group $G$ on a space $X$, I say it acts properly discontinuously if any $x\in X$ has a neighborhood $U\subset X$ so that $U\cap gU\neq\phi$ for all $g\in G$. If the action is properly discontinuous then the continuous action is reduced to the restrictions $\{g\}\times X\to X$ being continuous for all $g\in G$.

Comment: @RyanBudney The infinite earring that I have referred in my question is the same as Hawaiian earring. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: @JeremyBrazas I think my comments above could be shortened by saying that "if $X$ is path connected and admits a universal cover then for any covering $p:E\to X$ then the group $\mathrm{Deck}(p)$ has discrete topology". Does this sound plausible?

Comment: @MarkGrant thank for your comment. Thankfully Jeremy did make some comments. Yes, when the universal cover exists then its group of Deck transformations is the same as the fundamental group of the base (I assume base space is path connected). And from this, I think any covering of the base space would have discrete group of covering transformations.

Comment: @JeremyBrazas Could you please point at some of influential papers on the subject, and also at some places where some specific examples are worked out? At least some examples which justify that the topology on the Deck transformation group is not discrete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reiterate from my comments that a covering map is a discrete-sort-of-thing by definition, no matter what space you're looking at. If you are interested in non-discrete deck transformations or situations where such things are useful, there is a large literature on generalizations of covering space theory ([see my answer to this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165684/a-generalization-of-covering-spaces-to-fiber-bundles-with-totally-path-disconnec/165778#165778)). I don't know of a reference for the following claim but we can put together a short proof with some basic facts.

**Claim:** If $p:\widetilde{X}\to X$ is a covering map with $\widetilde{X}$ connected, then the subspace topology on $Deck(p)$ inherited from $Homeo(\widetilde{X})$ is discrete.

*Proof.* First, $Homeo(\widetilde{X})$ may not be a topological group, but it is a quasitopological group and is therefore homogeneous. So it suffices to show that the trivial subgroup $\{id\}$ is open in $Deck(p)$. Now, let's recall perhaps the strongest version of the uniqueness of lifts: If $Y$ is connected and $f,g:Y\to\widetilde{X}$ are maps such that $p\circ f=p\circ g$ and such that $f(y)=g(y)$ for at least one point $y\in Y$, then $f=g$. Applying this to our situation, we see that if $f,g\in Deck(p)$ agree on at least one point, then $f=g$.

Fix a point $\tilde{x}\in\widetilde{X}$ and let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $p(\tilde{x})$ that is evenly covered by $p$. Write $p^{-1}(U)=\coprod_{j\in J}V_{j}$ where $V_{j}$ is open and is mapped homeomorphically onto $U$ by $p$. We have $\tilde{x}\in V_{k}$ for some $k\in J$. Now $\mathcal{V}=\{f\in Deck(p)\mid f(\{\tilde{x}\})\subseteq V_{k}\}$ is an open neighborhood of $id$ in $Deck(p)$ (recall subbasic sets in the compact-open topology). If $f\in \mathcal{V}$, then $f(\{\tilde{x}\})\subseteq V_{k}\cap p^{-1}(p(\tilde{x}))=\{\tilde{x}\}$. Therefore, $f$ and $id$ agree at a point and must be equal. We conclude that $\{id\}=\mathcal{V}$ is open in $Deck(p)$. $\square$